# Parse string to date with "PST" format

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

In our application server is giving date time string in format like this
`"2013-01-14 T 06:33 PST"` and `"2013-01-14 T 06:33 PDT"` or `"2013-01-14 T 06:33 PLT"`

How could I parse those strings and get DateTime in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:-

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-01-14 21:09:06 PST".Replace("PST", "+2"), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm z", culture);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-01-14 21:09:06 PDT".Replace("PDT", "+2"), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm z", culture);
DateTime dt3 = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-01-14 21:09:06 PLT".Replace("PLT", "+2"), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm z", culture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the date time you can make conversions using `TimeZoneInfo`

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse("2013-01-14 T 06:33");
TimeZoneInfo PST = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
TimeZoneInfo yourZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pakistan Standard Time"); //For example
DateTime yourLocalTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTime, PST , yourZone );
```